# Help with .net mvc routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, nested-routes

I haven't been able to find something somewhat similar to rails nested resources.  I want to be able to define routes like

```
Contributors/3/Activities
```

which is just simply `ActivitiesController`, `Index`, with `Contributor_Id = 3`

I know I could manually define this specific route (I wouldnt know how) but what I'm looking for here is actually some recommendations on getting a flexible solution for these kind of scenarios.

Comment: This is an interesting question. In the app I'm working on now I've ended up defining all my routes by hand and it's a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Here](http://stevehodgkiss.github.com/restful-routing/)  and [Here](http://stevehodgkiss.com/posts/restful-routes-for-asp-net-mvc) to see if that might do the trick for you.
It is a custom routing engine for RESTful routes done by Steve Hodgkiss.

Comment: that looks promising.. although apparently it doesnt seem to work with razor?.. Ill check and post back